# Case insensitive dictionary for Pandas map lambda function

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, lambda

Below, I use `lambda x:`in a function to `map` value to a `pandas` column if they show up in the dictionary `benchmarks`.

In the example, a symbol `"GOOG"` is mapped as `"Google"` to the column `"full_name`".

My question is: How can I make a case insensitive check against the dict? So for instance, `"Aapl"` becomes `"Apple"` even though `"AAPL"` is in the dict.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.read_csv(file.csv, delimiter=",")
df = pd.DataFrame(["LONG GOOG VON", "Long Aapl X4 VON"], columns=["symbol"])

benchmarks = {"GOOG": "Google", "AAPL": "Apple"}
match = re.compile(r"\s(\S+)\s")

def f(value):
    f1 = lambda x: benchmarks[match.findall(x)[0]] if match.findall(x)[0] in benchmarks else ""
    stuff = f1(value)
    #stuff done here is omitted
    return stuff

df["full_name"] = df["symbol"].map(lambda x:f(x))
```

Comment: How about `flags=re.ignorecase`? Also, you might consider saving the regex search results instead of running it multiple times. Why do you even need a lambda if it's the only thing in the function? The function doesn't even `return` anything.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 That should work with `findall` according to the pandas docs, but I must be doing it wrong because it says that `'flags is an invalid keyword argument for this function'` when I enter it as `findall(x, flags=re.IGNORECASE)`

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 This is a slice of the full code. The returns are made elsewhere.

Comment: For compiled expressions, you have to put the flag in when compiling rather than when searching, e.g. `re.compile(r"\s(\S+)\s", flags=re.IGNORECASE)`.

Comment: Ah yes, I did try that also. A regex match is made for the word in `symbol` but doesn't translate with the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.IGNORECASE` when compiling the match, then convert the matched result to uppercase for the dictionary.

```
import re
a = ["LONG GOOG VON", "Long Aapl X4 VON", 'no matches here']
match = re.compile(r"\s(\S+)\s", re.IGNORECASE)
benchmarks = {"GOOG": "Google", "AAPL": "Apple"}
for element in a:
    s = match.search(element)
    if s:
        print(benchmarks.get(s.group(1).upper(), ''))
```

Result:

```
Google
Apple
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at this. But I'm not sure if that works with the way pandas keys columns (for `a =`). Also, can I use `s` as a substitute for `x` in my lambda function?

Comment: `s` is just a way to avoid having to regex search the string multiple times. Your `lambda`'s `x` is equivalent to `element`, the current string being searched.